# ORACLE PLS-00201: identifier 'VAT_REGISTER_AP.VAT_REG3' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, concurrent-programming, oracle-apps

I am new to oracle EBS. I have defined a concurrent program. Where i am calling package function **VAT_REGISTER_AP.Vat_REG3**

. Below is the syntax

```
    create or replace PACKAGE VAT_REGISTER_AP AS 
FUnction VAT_REG3--(P_STARTDATE IN DATE,P_EndDate IN Date,P_Legal_Enitity_ID IN NUMBER) 
RETURN sys_refcursor;
END;



  create or replace PACKAGE BODY VAT_REGISTER_AP AS 
FUNCTION  VAT_REG3--(P_STARTDATE DATE,P_EndDate Date,P_Legal_Enitity_ID IN NUMBER) 
RETURN sys_refcursor IS
R_RET sys_refcursor;
BEGIN 
OPEN R_RET
FOR
SELECT AL.TAX_RATE_CODE AS TaxCode,
AL.AMOUNT AS NetAMount,
AL.AMOUNT AS TaxAmount,
AI.Invoice_date AS ReportingDate,
AI.INVOICE_NUM AS InvoiceNumber,
AI.Invoice_date AS InvoiceDate,
AI.INVOICE_AMOUNT AS GrossAmount,
AI.INVOICE_NUM AS DocumentNumber ,
AI.Invoice_date AS DocumentDate,
AI.Vendor_ID AS SuplierID,
HZ.Tax_Reference AS SupplierVATNumber,
GL.Segment1 AS CompanyCode,
'AP' AS TransactionType
FROM APPS.AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL AL INNER JOIN APPS.AP_INVOICES_ALL AI ON
AI.INVOICE_ID=AL.INVOICE_ID INNER JOIN APPS.HZ_PARTIES HZ ON AI.Party_ID=HZ.PARTY_ID INNER JOIN apps.AP_INVOICE_distributions_ALL DL 
ON DL.INvoice_ID=AL.INVOICE_ID INNER JOIN APPS.GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GL ON GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID=DL.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID  where 
--AI.INVOICE_DATE Between p_StartDate and p_EndDate AND AI.LEGAL_ENTITY_ID=P_Legal_Enitity_ID AND 
rownum<200;
  return R_ret;
end;
END;
```

But when executing the concurrent program. I am facing below error.

```
ORACLE error 6550 in FDPSTP
```

Cause: FDPSTP failed due to ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'VAT_REGISTER_AP.VAT_REG3' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
.

The SQL statement being execute

How i can solve this?

Comment: how do you call the function? It should be called with `()`

Comment: It can be a grant issue. Please make sure you have proper grants to execute this Function in the Package.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. where can i check required privileges?

Comment: Can you post the syntax to call the function please?

Comment: To check grants use select * from all_tab_privs where table_name = 'your_func_name'... although this references tables this also does contain the grants for functions, procedures ect